# Should I use Static class for Database connectivity in C#.net?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class which contain all the database connection activities. What i want to know is should i make this class as static then i can call anywhere without creating it. 
but the application runs in different pcs in same network in same time.

OR ELSE

should i create a normal class that can be use in other classes by inheriting it?

Comment: what platform? asp.net? winforms? wpf? silverlight? if its a desktop app, doesn't matter if it runs on different PC's or not. static is local to the machine the code is running on.

Comment: You should look at implementing a singleton for the database connection.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider the fact that making classes static make them hard to unit test.

Here are two links that discuss the topic:
[Is static universally “evil” for unit testing and if so why does resharper recommend it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5757/is-static-universally-evil-for-unit-testing-and-if-so-why-does-resharper-recomm)

[Static Methods are Death to Testability](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/12/static-methods-are-death-to-testability.html)

Basically making things static also makes them hard to isolate and remove dependencies in.

Answer (score 2):

A static class might declutter your code somewhat. It's not a bad idea.

But I'm not sure what that has to do with the application running on different pcs on the same network.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from decluttering  there is a good reason why the class that makes database connection should be static. Usually in a application, one db connection is all you need. The way its usually designed is, you have a static class with a static method. On first call the static method checks if the connection object is null. If yes it creates a new connection and returns this. For future calls the method will just return this connection.
This also makes it simpler to make sure you close connection because now all you need is another static method in this class that closes this connection.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Example: imagine i had db class which contain db connection open closing methods within it. i implement a application with usage of this db class over my LAN. If person **A** open the connection to DB and from the other side person **B** also Open a DB connection. When i use static class is it indicate that DB connection already opened by some one. in this example would **B** get notified or Not?

Comment: Okay Sounds like you need connection pooling. But even without that, unless you describe our application a bit more , i think there is other standardized way to create this model of applications. When you have several applications running on lan which may access the database. there are two ways to implement this. 1. Let each of them  open a connection and take care of it. 2. Have a service running on the database host machine (a web service if you please) which opens just one connection. The applications on lan talk to this middle layer for all their database needs. does that help?

Comment: Actually my App is a POS system which use centralized db and more than one application running in pcs. I developed this POS through c#.net. I want to know if i declare database connection as Static is it become problem in other pc' though i install same application in other Pcs.

Answer (score 2):

> Do what you're best capable to deal
>   with.

The decision of making the data-access classes as `static` or not has got nothing to do with the purpose of the class in this case (which is purely data-access). More important is the fact is it should co-align with the overall design of your project or system and for you and for team-members it should be easy to maintain. I would recommend to split the classes based on table-access and make them symmetric in terms of design. Having said this, some important concerns that you should be careful about your data-access classes are...

- How are you going to deal with life-cycle of the database-connection(s) ?
- How are you going to deal with concurrency and caching(if used) ?

Answer (score 0):

don't use static class you can make your connection string static,because when multiple users are accessing static class can make problem

Answer (score 0):

I would not go for a static class.  It may declutter but there are always pros and cons.  I would also stay away from inheriting some base class.  As the GoF said: favour composition over inheritance.

So a factory would come in handy here:

```
    private IDatabaseConnectionFactory databaseConnectionFactory;

    public SomeClass() : this(new DatabaseConnectionFactory()) { }
    public SomeClass(IDatabaseConnectionFactory factory) 
    {
        databaseConnectionFactory = factory;
    }

    .
    .
    using (var connection = DatabaseConnectionFactory.Create()) { ... }
    .
    .
```

Where DatabaseConnectionFactory is injected or passed in.

HTH

Comment: This seems a bit advanced someone who's asking this type of question. But good advice for others.  :-)

Comment: @Richard: I agree :-) --- but the quicker one can move on the better.  This kind of thinking was quite an eye-opener when *I* encountered it so one never knows ;-)  It may just get the juices flowing.

Comment: Yes very true. Taking leaps sometimes is the way to go.

Comment: @Eben Roux: what would static class give some problems when it use in network environment? by the way the example u've mentioned is not comfortable with me. How can u guide me to write the code like this